# Posicionamento de blocos com FLEX-BOX

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Bom, estou fazendo um site onde na home há 4 módulos, os dois primeiros tem que estar um embaixo do outro, até ai tudo bem, só que o terceiro módulo tem que estar ao lado destes dois como se fosse uma coluna, primeiramente eu pensei vou colocar uma div em volta dos dois e até funcionou, mas ai surgiu outro problema, o 4 módulo teria que ficar em baixo do 1 e do 2 só que no layout que eu recebi, a versão mobile está nessa ordem onde o 4 módulo tem que ser embaixo da coluna da versão não mobile, então a minha pergunta é:

**- Na versão onde eu crio uma div para envolver os dois primeiros módulos, como eu faço para que o 4 módulo ocupe o espaço vazio?**

**Na versão onde eu não crio uma div para envolver os dois primeiros, existe um modo para que os dois primeiros fique embaixo um do outro o 3 ao lado dos dois e o 4 ocupando o espaço vazio abaixo dos dois primeiros?**

Lembrando que estou utilizando FLEX-BOX mas se tiver uma alternativa melhor aceito sugestões.

**Colocarei uma imagem para ilustrar de como deveria ficar**

[image: versão não mobile que seria o certo]

[image: versão não mobile que está dando errado]

**SOLUÇÃO FINAL**

Ao invés de usar flexbox usei a propriedade float mesmo da seguinte maneira:

**CSS**

```
.pai{ float:left} Largura qualquer
.pai .mod{ width:704px; float:left;}Envolve o módulo1 e 2()
.pai .modulo3{ width:296px; float:right; }Mod3 ocupa o lado direito
.pai .modulo4{ width:704px; float:left; }Ocupará o espaço vazio
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pai">
    <div class="mod">
        <div class="modulo1"></div>
        <div class="modulo2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modulo3"></div>
    <div class="modulo4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creio ser mais fácil de fazer usando `grid` e posicionando as `divs` onde quiser. Veja no exemplo abaixo que eu consigo posicionar as `divs` no local e com as dimensões que desejo. Obviamente que é apenas um exemplo que deve ser adaptado ao seu projeto.

> **Nota:** grid não tem suporte ao IE, porém pode ser feito um hack para corrigir.

```css
.pai {
   width: 220px;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
   grid-gap: 5px; 
   background-color: #fff; 
   color: #444; 
}

.filhos {
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   float:left;
   background: red;
}

.filhos:nth-child(2) {
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column: 1;
}


.filhos:nth-child(3) {
   width: 50px;
   height: 160px;
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column: 2;
   grid-row-end:span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filhos">
   1
  </div>
  <div class="filhos">
   2
  </div>
  <div class="filhos">
   3
  </div>
  <div class="filhos">
   4
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Guia do grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)**

---

### Utilizando Flex-Box

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}

.pai{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.filhos:nth-child(1),
.filhos:nth-child(2),
.filhos:nth-child(4){
  background: orange;
}

.filhos:nth-child(3){
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  order: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.filhos:nth-child(2){
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filhos">1</div>
    <div class="filhos">2</div>
    <div class="filhos">3</div>
    <div class="filhos">4</div>
</div>
```

**[Guia do flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Comment: Vou tentar aqui obrigado

Comment: ok, só uma observação, com flex-box não tem como fazer né? Só com GRID?

Comment: blz, eu só recorri aqui pq eu já pesquisei em um monte de lugar e não achei exatamente o que preciso, até estou tentando nth-child mas acho que não está funcionando

Comment: Testei o método do grid até que deu certo, exceto por que os conteúdo distribuirão sua altura uniformemente com a coluna

Comment: Poxa funcionou, vlw mesmo estava quebrando a cabeça aqui, só uma ultima coisa é que do jeito que vc fez a coluna e os outros filhos ficaram grudados lateralmente ai eu coloquei uma largura para a coluna e para o resto, só que a coluna não ficou na direita e sim no meio só consegui colocar na direita qdo dei um margin-left, será que tem alguma maneira de especificar que somente a coluna fique na direita com flex-box?

Comment: aee isso mesmo, vlw mano, ainda preciso aprender bastante sobre flex-box

Comment: Uma ultima coisa ess trecho "flex: 0 0 100%;" deixa a altura da coluna gigante e só sai se eu tiro o 100%, só que ai ele não fica mais na lateral

Comment: Não funcionou :( o que acontece é que quando ele vai para a lateral ele mantem tipo um fantasma de mesmo altura como se ele ainda estivesse lá, já tentei overflow:hidden; justify-self:start mas nada

Comment: @user4451 o problema está em deixar a div pai na altura da soma das 3 divs da esquerda... Realmente não tenho muito domínio sobre o flex-box. Mas uma solução seria aplicar o height na div pai por javascript: `divpai = document.querySelector('.pai');divfil = divpai.offsetHeight-document.querySelectorAll('.pai > .filhos')[3].offsetHeight;divpai.style.height = divfil+'px';`

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um modelo com `flexbox` apenas. Usei o atributo `order` para mudar a ordem do item 4 e o `flex-basis: 100%` no item 3 para deixar ele com 100% da altura do pai.

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
section>* {
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tres {
    background-color: hsl(72, 70%, 80%);
    order: 4;
}
.um {
    background-color: hsl(144, 70%, 80%);
    order: 1;
}
.dois {
    background-color: hsl(216, 70%, 80%);
    order: 2;
}
.quatro {
    background-color: hsl(288, 70%, 80%);
    order: 3;
}

.grid {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 16em;
}
.grid .um,
.grid .dois,
.grid .quatro {
    width: 80%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.grid .tres {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
    <div class="um">um</div>
    <div class="dois">dois</div>
    <div class="tres">tres</div>
    <div class="quatro">quatro</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Realmente!, não havia lembrado do flex-basis, é a solução +1

Comment: Vou testar aqui vlw

Comment: este seu método até funcionou mas a altura dos conteúdos acompanhavam a coluna e isso não podia acontecer, também a coluna tem que ter um espaço entre os outros elementos, mas vlw mesmo mano, hoje vcs me ajudaram mto

Comment: @user4451 cara para resolver isso coloque `section div { margin: 10px; }` e retire o `flex-grow: 1;` do .grid .um .dois .quatro , Se quiser posso editar o código original que fiz. O detalhe é que o .grid continua precisando de ter uma altura. []'s

Comment: Obrigado!! Utilizei a solução do DVD, mas vc tb mereceu um +1 :), Espero que seja de mta valia pro pessoal por que não encontrei dúvida parecida aqui no stack

Answer (score 1):

Somente com flexbox creio que não é possível, mas dá para uni-lo com float, para obter o resultado, a solução do DVD é a ideal caso não tenha de se preocupar com suporte entre browsers, já que grid ainda atinge 69.57% unprefixed.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ctn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    background: #333;
    }
.ctn > * {
  float: left;
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
}
.mod3 {
height: 90px;
float: right;
width: 20%;
}

@media all and (max-width : 600px) {

.ctn {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.mod3 {order: 3}
.mod4 {order: 4}

.ctn > * {flex: 1; width: 100%;}

}
```

```html
    <div class="ctn">
      <div class="mod3">Mod3</div>
      <div class="mod1">Mod1</div>
      <div class="mod2">Mod2</div>
      <div class="mod4">Mod4</div>
    <div>
```